# How can I draw a curve through as set of xyz points?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a list of data and want to make a curve like the one below which I made in solidworks. The problem of this curve is, that I don't know how to put it in a box with coordinates.

[image]

The best I could get in *Mathematica* are points connected with lines, which is not good enough. My code is:

```
Graphics3D[
  {Red, Line[pot], Black, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pot]}, 
  BoxRatios -> {3, 2, 1.5}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 450]
```

And this the image it produces:

[image]

Is there a solution?

Comment: If your points are not already ordered, `FindCurvePath` is useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I' ve already done what I wanted and it looks just the way it should. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your *(x,y,z)* data:

```
data = Table[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0`, 20, 0.05}];
```

Your parametric interpolating function:

```
intf = Interpolation[MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, data]];
```

Your plot:

```
ParametricPlot3D[intf[x], {x, 1, Length@data}]
```

[image]

If you don't keep the `data` you should note that the [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) assigned to `intf` also includes the range of data.  You can view it manually by looking at `intf` which will show the skeleton form of the expression, or you can extract it with `intf[[1, 1]]`.  Example:

```
ParametricPlot3D[intf[x], {x, ##}] & @@ intf[[1, 1]]
```

If your line looks odd you may need to adjust the [`InterpolationOrder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolationOrder.html) or [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html#711483517) options.